# Fix "no id given" message in method_missing

Tags: ruby

The following Ruby code raises the confusing error "no id given" shown at the end. How do I avoid this problem?

```
class Asset; end

class Proxy < Asset
  def initialize(asset)
    @asset
  end
  def method_missing(property,*args)
    property = property.to_s
    property.sub!(/=$/,'') if property.end_with?('=')
    if @asset.respond_to?(property)
      # irrelevant code here
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

Proxy.new(42).foobar
#=> /Users/phrogz/test.rb:13:in `method_missing': no id given (ArgumentError)
#=>   from /Users/phrogz/test.rb:13:in `method_missing'
#=>   from /Users/phrogz/test.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of this problem can be shown with this simple test:

```
def method_missing(a,*b)
  a = 17
  super
end

foobar #=> `method_missing': no id given (ArgumentError)
```

This error arises when you call `super` inside `method_missing` after changing the value of the first parameter to something other than a symbol. The fix? Don't do that. For example, the method from the original question can be rewritten as:

```
def method_missing(property,*args)
  name = property.to_s
  name.sub!(/=$/,'') if name.end_with?('=')
  if @asset.respond_to?(name)
    # irrelevant code here
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Alternatively, be sure to explicitly pass a symbol as the first parameter to `super`:

```
def method_missing(property,*args)
  property = property.to_s
  # ...
  if @asset.respond_to?(property)
    # ...
  else
    super( property.to_sym, *args )
  end
end
```

Comment: If you change the parameter, but only change it to a symbol, it will also work — you don’t have to explicitly pass it in the call to `super`. (e.g changing `a = 17` to `a = :"17"` in your example will result in `undefined method \`17' for ...`).

Comment: misleading `no id given (ArgumentError)` error message has been changed to `no symbol given` https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/1013